# Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: command-line, dpkg, root

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (21: Is a directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: Please add more detail to get help

Answer (score -1):

Your error says that `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is a directory. It's supposed to either be a regular file or not exist at all. See if `sudo rmdir /var/lib/dpkg/lock` works. (If it fails because there's stuff in it, move the stuff somewhere else then delete the directory.)